# How to restrict User can only edit their profile in django?

Tags: django

I want the user can edit their own profile, but can't edit other user's, how to make this kind of restriction in Django?

```
@login_required
def edit_profile:
  # some check
  pass
```

Comment: What seems to confuse you? When you're logged in, you'll get the user in request object. `request.user`
Then using `request.user.profile`, you can do whatever you want. It will, obviously, only happen on that user's profile.

Comment: Thanks, there has some error in my design of url pattern of this view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any restriction.  Just get the profile of the logged user and edit it:

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    profile = request.user.profile
    ...
```

Comment: So the url of the view edit_profile is something like '/edit_profile/', then get user information from request?

Comment: Yes @zbtong. The request should be made by the person whose profile it is. If not, send them a message that they aren't allowed to edit other people's profiles.

Comment: How can a user send a request to edit others profile if the url is '/edit_profile/'? @AshishNitinPatil

Comment: Yes.  All users will use the same url to edit their profiles and you will get the user's info from the `request.user`.

Comment: Oh, I missed that detail @zbtong.